# Google Sheets Query return autoincrement in results

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, auto-increment

I need to return a two column table from query where the first column shows the position order and then full name. So essentially in MySQL form it would be an autoincrement but I cannot get it to work. I'm using `=arrayformula(QUERY({G4:G18, arrayformula(row(G4:G18)) & ". " & H4:H18&" "&I4:I18, J4:J18}, "SELECT Col2, Col3 WHERE Col1 = 'Yes' ORDER BY Col3 ASC LABEL Col2 '', Col3 ''"))` which I realize the row(G4:G18) is just going to return the row number but I've tried everything else I can think of and can't get it to work. Any help is greatly appreciated.  **Note: I want to keep this in query form versus filter for various reasons. thanks.**

[image: Scenario]

[Sample sheet to see in action](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DpKyQsm88VLT3UugalmSGUsxEuvEMnAtgxGXPLwS170/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

I have come up with a solution but to do it, I need to have 2 queries. 1 that returns the Full name with incrementing numbers, and the other one which returns the Person ID. Please see screenshots below:

**1st query(for Full names with incrementing numbers):**

```
=INDEX(arrayformula(ifna(arrayformula(row(G4:G18)-3) & ". " & QUERY({G4:G18, H4:H18&" "&I4:I18, J4:J18}, "SELECT Col2, Col3 WHERE Col1 = 'Yes' ORDER BY Col3 ASC LABEL Col2 '', Col3 ''"), "")), 0, 1)
```

[image]

**2nd query(for the Person ID)**

```
=INDEX(arrayformula(QUERY({G4:G18, H4:H18&" "&I4:I18, J4:J18}, "SELECT Col2, Col3 WHERE Col1 = 'Yes' ORDER BY Col3 ASC LABEL Col2 '', Col3 ''")), 0, 2)
```

[image]

They are basically the same query, but I split them into two in order to concatenate an incrementing value to the Full names. I tried doing it using only 1 query but what happens is that the incrementing value will also be seen in the Person ID column(eg. 1. 2, 2. 3, 3. 5). Please let me know if this solution solves your problem.